# vertical align text to center in matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf

What's proper option to move text vertical center? Current code is located at lower left.

```
 %pdflatex -shell-escape a.tex 
\def\CONVERTCOMMAND{\convertexe\space -density \density\space \infile\space \ifx\size\empty\else -resize \size\fi\space -quality 90 -alpha off \outfile}
\documentclass[tikz,convert={true,density = 300,convertexe = {convert},
    command = {\noexpand\CONVERTCOMMAND},}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
   \matrix (m) at(0.09,0.76) [matrix of nodes,
    nodes={draw=blue!20,line width=0,outer sep=0,inner sep=0,text width=4.3cm,text height=28,align=left},%align=center
   ] {
  7/2/23 & AAA    & 000 & xxx  \\
  7/3/23 & BBB    & 111 & xxx  \\
  7/4/23 & CCC    & 222 & xxx  \\
  7/5/23 & DDD    & 333 & xxx  \\
 };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code (using  `anchor=center`)

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\def\CONVERTCOMMAND{\convertexe\space -density \density\space \infile\space \ifx\size\empty\else -resize \size\fi\space -quality 90 -alpha off \outfile}
\documentclass[tikz,convert={true,density = 300,convertexe = {convert},
    command = {\noexpand\CONVERTCOMMAND},}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \tikzset{centered matrix/.style={%
                matrix of nodes,
                nodes={draw=blue!20,line width=0,
                    minimum height=28pt,
                    text width=4.3cm,
                    anchor=center,
                    align=center,
                    inner sep=0pt,
                },
            },          
        }
        \matrix (m) at(0.09,0.76) [centered matrix]
     {
            7/2/23 & AAA    & 000 & xxx  \\
            7/3/23 & BBB    & 111 & xxx  \\
            7/4/23 & CCC    & 222 & xxx  \\
            7/5/23 & DDD    & 333 & xxx  \\
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: a]